# Disperse points in a 2D visualisation

Tags: r, visualization, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, points

I have a set of points like this (that I have clustered using R):

```
180.06576696, 192.64378568
180.11529253999998, 192.62311824
180.12106092, 191.78020965999997
180.15299478, 192.56909828000002
180.2260287, 192.55455869999997
```

These points are dispersed around a center point or centroid.

**The problem is that the points are very close together and are, thus, difficult to see.**

So, how do I move the points apart so that I can distinguish each point more clearly?

Thanks,

s

Comment: As this is not a question about [tag:cluster-analysis], I've retagged it to [tag:data-visualization]. For 2D data, rescaling seems the way to go. Consider a visualization that can visualize overlapping points.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the help. I added a bounty so fingers crossed.  One question, would I be better posting this question on cross-validated?

Comment: Not really, as it is more about visualization than any statistical method either. But to me it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve, or what you have tried.

Comment: Ok cool.  I will rephrase the question.

Comment: Why a simple scaling is not enough? Where do you want to visualize this points?

Comment: @Saphrosit, your right. I figured that out last night. I had gone down a bit of a rabbit hole. I am scaling it now, but I think I might still night to push the points out a little from the centroid.  I'll let you know, its online so I can show you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm overlooking some intricacy here, but...multiply by 10?

**EDIT**

Assuming the data you listed above are Cartesian (x,y) coordinate pairs, you can visualize them as a scatter plot using [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html).  I've rounded your data to 3 decimal places, because Google Charts doesn't appear to handle higher precision than that.

[image]

I don't know the coordinates for your central point.  In the above chart, I'm assuming it is somewhere nearby and not at (0,0).  If it is at (0,0), then I imagine it will be difficult to visualize all of the data at once without some kind of "zoom-in" feature, scaling the data, or a very large screen.

Comment: Thanks @Segphault, that helps but I think I have to find the distance of each point form the centroid, position each point in a cicrle around the centroid, and then increase the distance until the points are visible.  +1 for the ans.

Comment: Also, I need to rewrite the question, it is not very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

slotishtype, without going into code, I think you first need to add in the following tweaking parameters to be used by the visualization code.

Given an *x by y* display box, fill the entire box, with **input** parameters [0.0 to 1.0]...

- **overlap**:   the allowance for points to be placed on top of each other
- **completeness**:  how important is it to display *all* of your data points
- **centroid_display**: how important is it to see the *centroid* in the same output

These produce the dependent parameter

- **scale**: the ratio between display distances to numerical distances

You will need code to

- calculate the distance(s) to the centroid like you said,
- and also the **distances between data points**, affecting the output based on the *chosen* input parameters.

I take inspiration from the fundamentals in the GraphViz [dot manual](http://graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf). Look at the *"Drawing Orientation, Size and Spacing"* on p12.